# Should I wait until after my LLC's effective date to purchase equipment?

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, assets, purchase

I'm starting an LLC with an effective date of January 1, 2022. I would like to purchase some computer equipment ASAP so I can hit the ground running in January, but I won't have my LLC's bank account setup until after the first of the year and I'm not sure how a personal purchase in 2021 should be reflected in my LLC's bookkeeping in 2022.

If I make the purchase with my LLC's bank account after January 1, 2022, it seems like it would be easy. I would just make a contribution to my LLC's account and then purchase directly out of that account.

But is there any downside if I want to purchase equipment personally in 2021 and then transfer that equipment to the LLC in 2022? What is the best way to track this, bookkeeping-wise?

Thanks for any advice on how to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Technically you can contribute equipment just as you would contribute cash. But if your LLC is not pass-through or not a SMLLC, it may create some complications in depreciation schedule and allocations of partner basis. If your LLC is pass-through and single-member then it really doesn't matter, from tax perspective, and from book-keeping perspective you can just add it as an equity contribution.

If significant amounts are involved, you'll probably want a professional opinion from a CPA/EA.